# How is the end of round bonus calculated?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've found several very contradictory explanations / formulas how the end of match bonus in MW3 multiplayer is calculated.

I would be very grateful if someone could shed some light on this subject.  If you can, please provide reliable sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from a modder who hacked the game code:

```
Scaler = 1 if you win the match, 0.5 if you lose
spm = (3 + ( YOUR_RANK * 0.5 ) ) * 10
//maxmatchLength in seconds, YOUR_MATCHTIME in seconds (time it took to finish the match):
matchBonus = Scaler * ( ( maxmatchLength/60 ) * spm )  * (YOUR_MATCHTIME / maxmatchLength)
```

Obtained from [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/mw3/comments/mp0o1/how_is_the_match_bonus_calculated/).
Hope this helps!